# Get Subsite context from Root Site SharePoint Hosted App

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, jsom, sharepoint-hosted-app

I'm creating SharePoint Hosted App to create sub-sites for users. After creation I've to modify the user permissions on newly created Subsite. I'm trying following code.

```
function createSite()
    {
        var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        hostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
        appWebUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));
        var hostcontext = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostUrl);
        var web = hostcontext.get_web();
        context.load(web);
        var webTemplates = web.getAvailableWebTemplates(1033, false);
        context.load(webTemplates);
        context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            var enumerator = webTemplates.getEnumerator();
            var customTemplate;
            while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
                var webTemplate = enumerator.get_current();
                var webTitle = webTemplate.get_title();
                if (webTitle == templateTitle) 
                {
                    customTemplate = webTemplate.get_name();
                    break;
                }
            }
            //Sub-site creation code
            context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                alert("Site Created Successfully. Granting Permission started");
                var title = $("#txtSiteTitle").val();
                var eidNumber = $('#txtEID').val();
                var templateTitle = $('#siteType :selected').text()
                var clientUrl = title + eidNumber + templateTitle;
                clientSiteURL = hostUrl + "/" + clientUrl;
                BreakLibraryPermission(clientSiteURL)
            },
            function (sender, args)
            {
                alert("Site Creation Error:"+args.get_message());
            }
                );
        },
            function (sender, args) {
                alert("Get Template Error:"+args.get_message())
            }
        );

    }
    function BreakLibraryPermission(clientSiteURL)
    {
        var context = new SP.ClientContext(appWebUrl);
        var factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(appWebUrl);
        context.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
        var appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, clientSiteURL);
        var web = appContextSite.get_web();
        context.load(web);
        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, successHandler), Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandler));
        function successHandler() {
        alert("success" + web.get_title());
        }
        function errorHandler() {
            alert("Request failed: message = " + arguments[1].get_message());
        }

    }
```

Here in BreakLibraryPermission() function, inside successhandler, I'm not getting subsite context, In console I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: web is not defined` error.

Comment: Any error you are getting? If yes then post the error too..

Comment: @TrimantraSoftwareSolution There are no errors. Pls check the updated question

Comment: I believe you are using `while ` loop to iterate through your enumerator(Array) object?

Comment: @TrimantraSoftwareSolution Yes.. while (permissionEnum.moveNext()){}

Comment: Check updated answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with `executeQueryAsync` function in your `GetSubSitePermission()`.

`executeQueryAsync` function does not behave in sequential manner. So, you have to do some work around to force this function to behave as synchronously.

Please refer [Calling asynchronous JavaScript functions in a sequential manner](http://blog.portiva.nl/2015/09/24/calling-asynchronous-javascript-functions-in-a-sequential-manner/). Here you will come to know what is your problem and how to get rid of this issue.

Other references are:

1. [how to call executeQueryAsync() to behave synchronously?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/134932/how-to-call-executequeryasync-to-behave-synchronously)
2. [executeQueryAsync synchronously in each loop for sharepoint javascript model](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/162763/executequeryasync-synchronously-in-each-loop-for-sharepoint-javascript-model)

**Update:**

Just try replacing following line from your `BreakLibraryPermission` function:

```
var web = appContextSite.get_web();
```

to

```
web = appContextSite.get_web();
```

Comment: Thanks for your update.. But Its not working without enumeration too. Using the mentioned code, I'm not getting the context of sub-site even after get into success method.

Comment: ok. So if the codes are not so long then you can post the entire code too for more clarifications.

Comment: Pls check the updated question

Comment: After changing the web to subWeb in BreakLibraryPermission function, its working.. Thanks!!